# Apache2 on Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS Responding to Facebook Link Scraper with HTTP 418 "I'm a Teapot"

Tags: 20.04, apache2, facebook

I have a hosted virtual private server running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, recently upgraded from 18.x LTS. It’s running an Apache2 web server with a single domain. Since the upgrade it’s no longer possible to share links via Facebook, it returns a 418 “I’m a Teapot” HTTP response to the sharing debugger. I have no idea where this is coming from, nothing in the apache config files, robots.txt or .htaccess. Any suggestions where to look? I’m pulling my hair out with this one as link sharing via Facebook is very important. It does not affect other crawlers.

I have looked in all the config files and can’t see anything to cause this.

[Screenshot of Scraper Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skISE.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56189743

Comment: This is not an Ubuntu or Apache issue. The requested URL is the root of the domain you are running, so it is the application that _you_ are running that is reponding with the 418.

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but the User Guide page is plain html and still returns 418. This worked fine before, I have not changed anything except the version of Ubuntu / Apache. https://www.360shetland.co.uk/userguide/index.html